# C# append to open file

Tags: c#, file

I'm writing a C# application, where I log to a .CSV file using a streamwriter.

I can append to the file, but not if it is open by another program (excel)

Is there a way where I can append to the file while it is pen by excel. so that excel just pop up with a msb box saying that the file is updated.

Hope you can help, thanks and best regards 
Søren P.

Comment: No, the file is locked by Excel.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can write to a file only if the other application has opened it as SHARE WRITE. This is rare because it's very easy to corrupt the file if the applications don't cooperate. It's also more expensive as the OS needs to serialize possibly concurrent IO operations

Comment: Excel is not suitable for such job: Load data when new data arrive. See if http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020 fits your requirement.

Comment: Perhaps you're just trying to use Excel as a log viewer, the best you can do in this situation is find a Win32 version of the *nix command line `tail` app. (for example http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @DavidG Powershell does that already, and even formats the data as a table or a full UI Grid. The point is though - why open the file with Excel at all?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, but the link I gave is a proper UI for it. Not everyone is comfortable with command line.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ that's bypassing the question. The answer is *still* no - you can't open a file that is locked. In fact, unless the file is opened with `SHARE READ` you won't be able to open it even as Read Only

Comment: Instead of implementing your own logging code, use log4net or another logging library. They can handle writing, locking, formatting code so that you *don't* run into such problems. Exclusive locking though is typically faster, which is why it's the default option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that excel and other office products are locking the file while its open. Other tools like notepad++ are usually a bit more nice and don't lock a file.

Thus sadly no there is no way to modify the file until the lock is solved. You could only wait for the file to get unlocked again (aka closed in excel) and then write to it, but while its open and thus locked you can't write to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the file is locked by Excel you can try the following:

```
// Get the excel application instance.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

// Get the workbook you need to modify (where "WorkbookName" is the name of the Workbook).
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks["WorkbookName"];

// Close the workbook without saving - you can now modify the file.
workbook.Close(false, false, false);
```

You may need to modify this pattern based on your exact needs - i.e. you may want Excel to save any changes to the file before closing.

Comment: Modifying logging code to use Excel Interop isn't the best idea and will result in significant performance delays. Besides, this doesn't answer the question at all - what happens if the user uses Libre or any other program to view the file?

Comment: Also experience wise the interop utilities are sadly not the most stable so they should be avoided if possible (had the problem with other parts of the interop utilities in the past)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't as the file is locked. You can kill the blocking process, but that's not what you want in this case.